# Print Unique Id in logger for each method call in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, logging

I have spring boot kafka consumer which is consuming the message. I want to add unique id for each consumed message in the each logger. The logging statement is more then 1000 I dont want to edit each logger to log the unique ID.

Can someone please help me with the better aproach?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please further more explain what you require?

Comment: You could probably use a custom `Layout` to do this [in Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html)